# Dynamically Map an Image in "Brick"

Tags: jquery, html, image, mapping

What I'm trying to do is mapping an Image dynamically..

I'll make and example to be more specific! Let's say I've this image

[image: base-image]

Now, let's say I've a .xml file where I save some news.. What I want is to divide the image here into "brick", where each one will be a link for the news! So, I would have the image like this:

[image: image-brick]

Divided into brick! In this example, since I've just 2 news in .xml file, only two brick will be "clear", the rest of the image will be darker.

I'll have like 15 max news, so the image will be divided in 3x5 or 5x3, but the widith of the brick should be dynamic since this should be display regardless the width of window browser.

I'm open to use Jquery, CSS and whatever it's needed!

EDIT: the only "easy" solution I've found so far is that I create 15 image, where in each one I'll have one more brick "clear".. Then i'll load the proper image via Jquery and put the link only for the clear brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id='image'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='1'></div>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='2'></div>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='3'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='4'></div>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='5'></div>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='6'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='7'></div>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='8'></div>
    <div class='cell empty' data-id='9'></div>
  </div>
</div>
#image
{
  background-image:url(https://ramiteks.lv/atteli/kontakti/vecpiebalga/400/IMG_0142.JPG);
  width:400px;
  height:265px;
}
.row
{
  width:100%;
  height:33.3%;
}
.cell
{
  width:33.3%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
.empty
{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

var array_from_xml = Array('a','b','c','d');
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i=0;i<array_from_xml.length;i++)
  {
    $('.cell[data-id='+(i+1)+']').removeClass('empty');
    $('.cell[data-id='+(i+1)+']').html(array_from_xml[i]);
  }
});
```

Look at fiddle it uses jquery  - https://jsfiddle.net/h0meyf9p/4/